# How to UPIVOT all columns in a table and aggregate into Data Quality/ Validation Metrics? SQL SNOWFLAKE

Tags: sql, validation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot, data-quality

I have a table with 60+ columns in it that I would like to UNPIVOT so that each column becomes a row and then find the fill rate, min value and max value of each entry.

For Example

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | EVENT_ID | PROVIDER_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01/23/21 | 03/14/21 | 0023401 | 0012323 |
| 02 | 06/04/21 | 09/20/21 | 0025906 | 0023454 |
| 03 | 07/20/21 | 12/02/21 | 0027093 | 0034983 |

And I want the output to look like

| Column_Name | Fill_Rate | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | 0.7934 | 01 | 03 |
| Start_Date | 0.6990 | 01/23/21 | 07/20/21 |
| End_Date | 0.9089 | 03/14/21 | 12/02/21 |
| Event_ID | 1.0000 | 0023401 | 0027093 |

Struggling to get the desired output, especially because of different data types in the different columns

i tried doing the following, but it doesn't allow taking the agg functions within the unpivot

```
select *
from "DSVC_MERCKPAN_PROD"."COHORTS_LATEST"."MEDICAL_HEADERS"
UNPIVOT (
max(code) as max_value,
min(code) as min_value,
avg(code) as fill_rate,
code as column_name
)
```

For fill rate, I was trying to use this logic as ID is always populated so it has the total number of rows, however the other columns can be null

```
 (COUNT_IF(start_date is not null))/(COUNT_IF(ID is not null))) as FILL_RATE,
```

Comment: Hi - please update your quest with the SQL you have managed to write so far on your own and explain how you are calculating the fill_rate, min and max? Also, why is the datatype of a column causing you issues? The MAX function, for example, works regardless of datatype - so is the MAX default behaviour not what you are looking for?

Comment: @NickW , well originally I tried to create the output with a series of union all queries but there are so many columns that this was extremely inefficient and the way that I was trying to create the fill rate wasnt compatible with certain types of data such as date.

Comment: `count` does not count nulls (in any database) so you don't need to use `count_if`, but instead you can use `avg(column_name)` of it decomposed `sum(col_name)/count(col_name)` both will give you the average, the former is safe when there are zero total rows, thus if you really want to do the math yourself, `div0(sum(col_name),count(col_name))` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ideas to implement the report.

The first way is casting all values to `VARCHAR` and then using `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
-- Generate dummy data
create or replace table t1 (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int, c6 int, c7 int, c8 int, c9 int, c10 int) as
select
    iff(random()%2=0, random(), null), iff(random()%2=0, random(), null),
    iff(random()%2=0, random(), null), iff(random()%2=0, random(), null),
    iff(random()%2=0, random(), null), iff(random()%2=0, random(), null),
    iff(random()%2=0, random(), null), iff(random()%2=0, random(), null),
    iff(random()%2=0, random(), null), iff(random()%2=0, random(), null)
from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000000))
;

-- Query
with
cols as (
    select column_name, ordinal_position
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_catalog = current_database()
    and table_schema = current_schema()
    and table_name = 'T1'
),
stringified as (
    select
        c1::varchar c1, c2::varchar c2, c3::varchar c3, c4::varchar c4, c5::varchar c5,
        c6::varchar c6, c7::varchar c7, c8::varchar c8, c9::varchar c9, c10::varchar c10
    from t1
),
data as (
    select column_name, column_value
    from stringified
    unpivot(column_value for column_name in (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10))
)
select
    c.column_name,
    count(d.column_value)/(select count(*) from t1) fill_rate,
    min(d.column_value) min,
    max(d.column_value) max
from cols c
left join data d using (column_name)
group by c.column_name, c.ordinal_position
order by c.ordinal_position
;
/*
COLUMN_NAME FILL_RATE   MIN MAX
C1  0.500000    -1000000069270747870    999999972962694409
C2  0.499980    -1000000027928146782    999999946877079818
C3  0.499996    -1000000012155323098    999999942281548701
C4  0.500017    -1000000056353213091    999999946421698482
C5  0.500015    -1000000015608859996    999999993977648967
C6  0.500003    -1000000007081089270    999999998851014730
C7  0.499987    -100000008605944993 999999968272328033
C8  0.499992    -1000000042470913027    999999977402822725
C9  0.500011    -1000000058928465662    999999969060696774
C10 0.500029    -1000000011306371004    99999996061390938
*/
```

It's a straightforward way, but it still needs to list up all column names twice and it's a bit tough in the case the number of columns is very massive (but I believe it's much better than a huge UNION ALL query).

---

Another solution is a bit tricky, but you can unpivot a table by using `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*)` aggregation if the row length doesn't exceed a VARIANT value limit (16 MiB):

```sql
with
cols as (
    select column_name, ordinal_position
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_catalog = current_database()
    and table_schema = current_schema()
    and table_name = 'T1'
),
data as (
    select f.key column_name, f.value::varchar column_value
    from (select object_construct(*) rec from t1) up,
    lateral flatten(up.rec) f
)
select
    c.column_name,
    count(d.column_value)/(select count(*) from t1) fill_rate,
    min(d.column_value) min,
    max(d.column_value) max
from cols c
left join data d using (column_name)
group by c.column_name, c.ordinal_position
order by c.ordinal_position
;

/*
COLUMN_NAME FILL_RATE   MIN MAX
C1  0.500000    -1000000069270747870    999999972962694409
C2  0.499980    -1000000027928146782    999999946877079818
C3  0.499996    -1000000012155323098    999999942281548701
C4  0.500017    -1000000056353213091    999999946421698482
C5  0.500015    -1000000015608859996    999999993977648967
C6  0.500003    -1000000007081089270    999999998851014730
C7  0.499987    -100000008605944993 999999968272328033
C8  0.499992    -1000000042470913027    999999977402822725
C9  0.500011    -1000000058928465662    999999969060696774
C10 0.500029    -1000000011306371004    99999996061390938
*/
```

`OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*)` aggregation is a special usage of the `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` function that extracts column names as a key of each JSON object. As far as I know, this is the only way to extract column names from a table along with values in a programmatic way.

Since `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` is relatively a heavy operation, it usually takes a longer time than the first solution, but you don't need to write all column names with this trick.